# Native email app showing email account password on lock screen of Galaxy S2

Tags: email, lock-screens, password

Dear Android community,

Recently I have set up a personal email account on the native email client that comes with the version of Android I have (4.1.2). After I have set it up and could receive/send/sync emails and all, I have decided to remove that account from the native client.

Now, the password that I used with that email account via that native email client is being displayed on my lock screen, under the time.

I want to not see it there anymore (obviously!). Has anybody had the problem before ? Any idea on how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

Look in **Settings -> Security -> Owner Info**.

It is the only one place, to my knowledge, where you can set up text under the clock on the lockscreen before 4.2.